# C++ lambda and operator syntax

Tags: c++, lambda, overloading, operator-keyword

I last used C++  in 2003, and am trying to revisit, and learn the new stuff.  Have been working in Java for a while, and just learning its Lambda syntax.  Saw this example in C++, and wondering if someone could explain it:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int i = 42;
char code = 'c';

[=, &i]() mutable
{
    i++;
    code = 'd';
    std::cout << "i: " << i << "code " << code << std::endl;
}();


void wait()
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "i: " << i << "code " << code << endl;


    // hold output window open
    wait();
    return 0;
}
```

Is this new lambda syntax for operator= overload?  I'd write a test function, but am not sure how to invoke it.

Comment: No it's not. Have you tried running it and observing what happen?

Comment: No it is not. You should do some reading on lambdas. As a sidenote, this `<< cout::endl;` will not compile.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11

Comment: I understand the keywords (reference, mutable, etc), but as I am new to this specific syntax in C++, I am unsure how to even execute this method. Surprised at the instantaneous downvote (which implies the answer is obvious).  Stating "No it is not" does not assist.  What is the 1-line needed to test the method?  If I can see how to invoke it, then I am off an running.  Kind Regards,...

Comment: @Pierre Baret: this portion of link helped:  You can capture by both reference and value, which you can specify using & and = respectively:

        [&epsilon] capture by reference
        [&] captures all variables used in the lambda by reference
         [=] captures all variables used in the lambda by value
        [&, epsilon] captures variables like with [&], but epsilon by value
        [=, &epsilon] captures variables like with [=], but epsilon by reference

Answer (score 0):

The `=` means it will capture all variables by value, `&i` specifies that `i` must be captured by reference.

The `mutable` means it can change input parameters values. And as there are none this has no effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` before the lamda is the capture list for the lambda. If it says `[=]`, it captures all automatic variables used in the lambda by copy. In your case this will mean `i` is captured by reference and `code`(the other automatic variable used inside the lambda) is captured by copy.

The `mutable` means that the variables are captured mutably, so the lambda can change the captured variables. But the lambda here doesn't change any captured variables  anyways ...

Answer (score 0):

I can't reply back to comments as I still don't have 50 rep points (my previous answer was automatically moved to comments as it was just a link).

I found a simple way of testing lambda expressions but I quite don't understand the purpose of your code sample so I am posting it raw here. I hope it helps, it is from the Book SFML Game Development, and uses `std::functions`

```
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b };
// Assign a lambda expression to a function
std::function<int(int, int)> adder1 = [] (int a, int b) { return a + b; };

int sum = adder1(3, 5); // same as add(3, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for your assistance.  Found detailed explanation here, : [section "How are Lambda closures implemented"](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html)